# Grails automatically coerce strings into one of my domain classes

Tags: data-binding, grails, groovy, grails-domain-class, type-coercion

I have a domain class like:

```
class MyDomainClass{
  String name
}
```

And an interface with a signature like:

```
BigDecimal doBigThangs(MyDomainClass startHere)
```

I want to be able to call it like this

```
doBigThangs('stuff')
```

And have it automatically coerse the string 'stuff' into the appropriate MyDomainClass.  This is what I have tried, but perhaps I need to use "asType" or something.

```
ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally()
String.metaClass.toMyDomainClass = {->MyDomainClass.findByNameLike(delegate)}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use simple polymorphism to handle this?

Comment: I'll go try to finally understand polymorphism and let you know :p

Comment: It seems like "polymorphism" just means "implements an interface" which still leaves me with the question: how do I implement that interface on String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: you can add a type conversion by overriding `asType`.  Your example would look something like this:

```
oldAsType = String.metaClass.getMetaMethod("asType", [Class] as Class[])
String.metaClass.asType = { Class c ->
    if (c == MyDomainClass) { 
        MyDomainClass.findByNameLike(delegate)
    } else {
        oldAsType.invoke(delegate, c)
    }
}
```

However, groovy won't silently cast a String to another type on a method call.  You'll have to call your method like this:

```
doBigThangs('stuff' as MyDomainClass)
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I was looking for.  Is there some way to use something like `super()` instead of the `oldAsType` thing?  I'm trying to get my head around the all the groovy concepts.

Comment: As far as I know, once you overwrite the `asType` metaMethod, the old one is gone unless you saved a reference.

Comment: Mine crashes without writing "def oldAsType" by my understanding was the def was only necessary to make things local... weird.